# .net core 2.2 DB connection errors full stack trace

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, .net-core

I have an application running in .net core 2.2 with DBContextPool.

I'm doing load testing on the application and it seems to crash under high load; it seems an SQL query (I'm connecting to MySQL database) is timing out. The error I get is here:

```
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Connect Timeout expired. ---> System.OperationCanceledException: The operation was canceled.
at System.Threading.CancellationToken.ThrowOperationCanceledException()
at System.Threading.SemaphoreSlim.WaitUntilCountOrTimeoutAsync(TaskNode asyncWaiter, Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at MySqlConnector.Core.ConnectionPool.GetSessionAsync(MySqlConnection connection, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\Core\ConnectionPool.cs:line 42
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.CreateSessionAsync(Nullable`1 ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\MySql.Data.MySqlClient\MySqlConnection.cs:line 507
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.CreateSessionAsync(Nullable`1 ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\MySql.Data.MySqlClient\MySqlConnection.cs:line 523
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.OpenAsync(Nullable`1 ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\MySql.Data.MySqlClient\MySqlConnection.cs:line 232
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenDbConnectionAsync(Boolean errorsExpected, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
[41m[30mfail[39m[22m[49m: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query[10100]
An exception occurred while iterating over the results of a query for context type 'SuponicPay.Repository.Data.SuponicPayDbContext'.
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Connect Timeout expired. ---> System.OperationCanceledException: The operation was canceled.
at System.Threading.CancellationToken.ThrowOperationCanceledException()
at System.Threading.SemaphoreSlim.WaitUntilCountOrTimeoutAsync(TaskNode asyncWaiter, Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at MySqlConnector.Core.ConnectionPool.GetSessionAsync(MySqlConnection connection, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\Core\ConnectionPool.cs:line 42
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.CreateSessionAsync(Nullable`1 ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\MySql.Data.MySqlClient\MySqlConnection.cs:line 507
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.CreateSessionAsync(Nullable`1 ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\MySql.Data.MySqlClient\MySqlConnection.cs:line 523
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.OpenAsync(Nullable`1 ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\MySql.Data.MySqlClient\MySqlConnection.cs:line 232
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenDbConnectionAsync(Boolean errorsExpected, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean errorsExpected)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.BufferlessMoveNext(DbContext _, Boolean buffer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.Storage.Internal.MySqlExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNext(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Linq.AsyncEnumerable.SelectEnumerableAsyncIterator`2.MoveNextCore(CancellationToken cancellationToken) in D:\a\1\s\Ix.NET\Source\System.Interactive.Async\Select.cs:line 106
at System.Linq.AsyncEnumerable.AsyncIterator`1.MoveNext(CancellationToken cancellationToken) in D:\a\1\s\Ix.NET\Source\System.Interactive.Async\AsyncIterator.cs:line 98
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncLinqOperatorProvider.ExceptionInterceptor`1.EnumeratorExceptionInterceptor.MoveNext(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Connect Timeout expired. ---> System.OperationCanceledException: The operation was canceled.
at System.Threading.CancellationToken.ThrowOperationCanceledException()
at System.Threading.SemaphoreSlim.WaitUntilCountOrTimeoutAsync(TaskNode asyncWaiter, Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at MySqlConnector.Core.ConnectionPool.GetSessionAsync(MySqlConnection connection, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\Core\ConnectionPool.cs:line 42
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.CreateSessionAsync(Nullable`1 ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\MySql.Data.MySqlClient\MySqlConnection.cs:line 507
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.CreateSessionAsync(Nullable`1 ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\MySql.Data.MySqlClient\MySqlConnection.cs:line 523
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.OpenAsync(Nullable`1 ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\MySql.Data.MySqlClient\MySqlConnection.cs:line 232
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenDbConnectionAsync(Boolean errorsExpected, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean errorsExpected)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.BufferlessMoveNext(DbContext _, Boolean buffer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.Storage.Internal.MySqlExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNext(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Linq.AsyncEnumerable.SelectEnumerableAsyncIterator`2.MoveNextCore(CancellationToken cancellationToken) in D:\a\1\s\Ix.NET\Source\System.Interactive.Async\Select.cs:line 106
at System.Linq.AsyncEnumerable.AsyncIterator`1.MoveNext(CancellationToken cancellationToken) in D:\a\1\s\Ix.NET\Source\System.Interactive.Async\AsyncIterator.cs:line 98
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncLinqOperatorProvider.ExceptionInterceptor`1.EnumeratorExceptionInterceptor.MoveNext(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

As you can see, the stack trace stops while still inside the EF Core library.

Is there any way to display the full stack trace? All the way up to my service/controller level code?

I can then determine the cause of this much more easily.

Comment: Checking a mysql connection pool size could be an option. How many simultanious connections are allowed?

Comment: A lot of simultaneous connections, I actually solved the connection issue through other means, but the important point of this question is how can I get the stack trace up to my code (out of the EF core library). I think it will help me debug other issues as well

Comment: If exception is re-thrown there would be no way to catch original stack trace except changing the source code itself (which also could be an option if the adapter is open sourced).

Comment: @l3utterfly - how did you solve your problem? I'm facing similar issues and all i get is below

`
System.OperationCanceledException: The operation was canceled.
   at System.Threading.CancellationToken.ThrowOperationCanceledException()
   at System.Threading.SemaphoreSlim.WaitUntilCountOrTimeoutAsync(TaskNode asyncWaiter, Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
`